# Trying to decode hex to binary representation in C#

Tags: c#, python, redis, bitarray

I'm saving a `bitarray` (40 bits) from Python (using bitarray lib) to Redis.
When I retrieve this value from Redis, I get: `\xe8\x00\x00\x00\x00`

How do I convert this value to "01010101" in C#?

Thank you!

EDIT:

When i use this form:
http://easycalculation.com/hex-converter.php, the binary value returned is what i'm expecting.

Comment: Does this help? http://alperguc.blogspot.ca/2008/11/c-convert-hexadecimal-to-binary-string.html

Comment: I already tried this but it's not working.

Comment: With the values you've given, "E8, 00, 00, 00, 00", what are you expecting? And how are your values in C# represented?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this:

```
// Chop up the string into individual hex values
string[] hexStrings = hexString.Split(new[] { "\\x" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

// Convert the individual hex strings into integers
int[] values = hexStrings.Select(s => Convert.ToInt32(s, 16)).ToArray();

// Convert the integers into 8-character binary strings
string[] binaryStrings = values.Select(v => Convert.ToString(v, 2).PadLeft(8, '0')).ToArray();

// Join the strings together
string binaryString = string.Join("", binaryStrings);
```

EDIT - Here's an example of what you could do if you want to use a `BitArray`:

```
// Chop up the string into individual hex values
string[] hexStrings = hexString.Split(new[] { "\\x" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

// Convert the individual hex strings into bytes
byte[] bytes = hexStrings.Select(s => Convert.ToByte(s, 16)).ToArray();

BitArray bitArray = new BitArray(bytes);
```

Comment: Nice, thank you! But "complicated", there is no way to do it just with a BitArray ? In fact i would like to check a bit based on a position.

Comment: @Grégory I've edited my answer to include a `BitArray` example.

Comment: when i try with the BitArray sample, bitArray[0] returns FALSE instead of TRUE

Comment: @Grégory Keep in mind that the first character in the bit string is the most significant bit (MSB) in the first byte. `bitArray[0]` is checking the LSB in the first byte. The first character in the bit string is actually `bitArray[7]`. You can read more about it in the remarks section here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x1xda43a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx